# Coloring cell according to constraints

Tags: excel

Is it possible to coloring cells using some simple constraints (for these I assume columns don't have letters but numbers):

1. Statring cell (x0, y0) and ending cell (x1, y1)
2. Cells must fulfill equation (x, 2x)

For instance I select cell begin (1,1) and end (10, 10)
Coloring should happens to (1,1) (2,3) (3,5) (4,7) (5,9) and that's it since (6,11) would go out of bound for y.

[image]

If it's possible could you tell me how it can be done?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the coordinates (1,1), (2,3), etc fulfill the condition (x,2x)...

Comment: @deathApril
http://postimg.org/image/6h0rahupt/

here it would be nice if I can choose starting cell (1,1) is just example, and condition (x, 2x) as well. I would like be able to use any linear function.

Comment: @Jerry might be (x,2x-1) does it really matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple macro will accomplish this:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100  'Instead of 100, put your upper number here.
    With Cells(i, i * 2).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
 Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx) with a formula like this:

```
=ROW()*2=COLUMN()+1
```